# Properties of a function such that $f(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt$

Tags: integration, functions

Suppose a continuous function $ y=f(x)$ satisfies:
$$f(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt$$
Then which of the following DOES NOT hold:

1. $f$ is periodic
2. $f$ is differentiable for all $x \in \mathbb R$
3. Range of $f$ is a singleton
4. $f$ is neither odd nor even

I know that the case for $2$ is true because I tried differentiating the function. I also know that
$4$ is true because I tried putting $-x$ in the function. I am confused between $1$ and
$3$.

Comment: $f$ satisfies the equation $y'=y$, with the initial condition $y(0)=0$. Are you able to conclude that $f(x)=0$?

Answer (score 2):

We have $f'(x)=f(x)$. So integrating we get$f(x)=Ae^x$. But $f(0)=0$, so $f(x)=0$ for all $x$. Hence (1)-(3) are true and (4) is false.

Comment: Interestingly, the function is periodic with any period. It is also both even and odd !

Comment: Agree, the function is both odd and even.